# Determining details of a cache

Tags: c, caching, associative

> Your machine has an L1 cache and memory with the following properties.
>
> - Memory address space: 24 bits
> - Cache block size: 16 bytes
> - Cache associativity: direct-mapped
> - Caches size: 256 bytes

I am asked to determine the following: 1. the number of tag bits. 2. the number of bits of the cash index. 3. number of bits for cache size.

1. tag bits = m - (s+b)

   m = 24. s = log2 S, S = C/(B*E). E = 1 due to it being direct mapped. so S = 256/16 = 16. s = log2 16 = 4. B = 16 (cache block size) b = log2 B; which is log2 16= 4. so s=4,b=4,m=24. t = 24-(4+4) = 16 total tag bits.
2. I am not sure how to figure this out.
3. I believe number of bits for cache size is just C*(num bits/byte) = 256*8 = 2048.

Can anyone help me figure out 2., and determine if the logic in 1. & 3. are correct?

Comment: If the total address space is 24 bits, then the number of tag bits has to be less than 24. In other words, I'm not sure where you got `m=32`.

Comment: I misinterpreted the question, m should be 24.

Comment: For your future information: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.  Thank you!

Comment: my mistake @D.W. the CS thread seemed dead so I asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This is correct for m=32 (isn't it 24?).

2) The number of index-bits: The number of bits to address a block in the cache when it'd direct-mapped, since it identifies the set (which consists only of one block in this case). If it was 2-way, one bit less would be needed for the index (and added to the tag-bits). For this problem, Since there are 16 sets you need 16 index bits which can be represented in 4 index bits.

3) It is not completely clear how to interpret this question. I would understand it as the number of bits needed to address the cache, which would be 4 in this case? If indeed, as you assume, the number of bits in the cache was meant, you would have to add 16*16 bits for the tag bits to your solution.

Comment: how do you determine how many bits are needed to address the cache?

Comment: To address a cacheline you need log2(cachesize/blocksize) bits. However, I am not entirely sure what is meant. Did you translate it yourself to english?

Comment: No, this is an exact copy of the question that is provided on my practice final for a Computer Architecture class, @ctx

Comment: Perhaps the caveat with 3 is, that you have to add the bits needed for the tag. The tag must be stored, too, for each cacheblock, since it must be compared with the actual address. In this case, the result would be 2048+16*16. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: so what is the actual answer to 2? is it just 1?

Comment: Since english is your native language, not mine, I assume that you interpret the question correctly. The result would then be 2048+16*16 bits I think. I meant question 2 in my previous comment, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98042/discussion-between-bkennedy-and-ctx).